# Connection could not be established with host free.mboxhosting.com [Connection refused #111] with laravel in free hosting

Tags: php, laravel, email, environment-variables

I've been hosted my laravel project in a free hosting (in awardspace). Everything works ok, except sending email. When I try to send an email by compiling the form from the contact page of my project, it returns me this error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host free.mboxhosting.com [Connection refused #111]
```

This is the outgoing mail settings that free hosting service offers:

[image]

This is how i've been set the file .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=free.mboxhosting.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=contatti@pprivitera.dx.am
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=contatti@pprivitera.dx.am
MAIL_FROM_NAME=User
```

And this is how I've been set the config/mail.php file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'free.mboxhosting.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'contatti@pprivitera.dx.am'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'User'),
],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),
'username' => env('contatti@pprivitera.dx.am'),
'password' => env('mypassword')
```

Tests I did:

1)I tried to change `MAIL_DRIVER` from `"smtp"` to `"sendmail"` both from .env file and from the mail.php file, but it doesn't work because the website after 4 minutes of loading returns me: `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` (I don't understand why, because in local the contact form works perfectly and anyway the Route `/contact/submit` is set as `::post` and the method of my contact form is set as `"=post"` too)

2)I tried to change the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` from `"ssl"` to `"null"` so I've changed also the port from `465` to `25` or `587` (both from .env file and from the config/mail.php file) but it returns me the error `([Connection refused #111])`

3)I tried to use mailtrap with my credential, both with `ssl` encryption and with `null` encryption, using 2525 port or 465 (depend from encryption type used), but it returns me the same error:

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111]
```

4)With mailtrap if I change the `MAIL_DRIVER` from `smtp` to `sendmail`, it returns me the error that I've described in the 1st point

5)In my local machine everything works perfectly, just using mailtrap with `MAIL_DRIVER` set as `smtp` and the rest of configuration set with credential of my mailtrap account

I don't understand what's wrong in the configuration. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try and see if can adjust any firewall settings in your free hosting?

Comment: Unfortunately there are no firewall settings in my free hosting which I can change

Comment: You may want to contact their support then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` as `tls`. I think that this encryption will to works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this two:

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls   
MAIL_PORT=25
```